# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer becouse of nullpointer

Tags: c, typedef, null-pointer

Hej, I have some code in C, that dosent work. I am just trying to get a price from typedef potatoes to my check-out fuction. I "//" the code which is not in use. I there are needed more info please just ask, though I have no clue how to get pas this problem. So any help is much appreciated.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>   

    int number;

    void get_number ( );
    void show_menu ( );
    int get_input ( );
    void chech_out ();

    struct Product 
    {
            float potatoes;
    };
    typedef struct Product product;

    int main (void)
    {
        struct Product product;

        while (1)
        {
            //show_product1 ();
            show_menu ();
            if (get_input ()) // end on "a"
                break;
        }
        printf ("Bye!");
        return 0;
    }



    void show_menu (void)
    {
        printf ("Type what you wanne do");
        printf ("f)change amount    h)chech out    s)Strawberry");
        printf ("c)carrots    p)potatoes  o)Onion");
        printf ("a)quit");
    }

    void get_number ( )
    {

        printf ("Enter number in kg: ");
        scanf ("%d", &number);
    }



    int get_input (struct Product *product )
    {
        char letter;

        scanf ("%c", &letter);
        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'f':
                printf("\n\n\nWhenever you enter a new amount it will reset the old one!\n\n");

                break;
            case 'h':
                chech_out();


                break;
            case 'c':

                break;
            case 'p':


                get_number();           
                float P_freightPrice = number*12;
                float P_kgPrice = number*25;
                float P_totalprice=P_freightPrice+P_kgPrice;
                product->potatoes = P_totalprice;
           printf("\n%f\n",P_totalprice);     

         if (P_totalprice <= 100)
         {
           printf("%f\n",P_totalprice);    
         }
         if (P_totalprice>=101 && number<=350)
         {
             float New=(P_totalprice/100)*5;
             float total=P_totalprice-New;
             printf("%f\n",total);    
         }
         if(P_totalprice>=351 && P_totalprice<=600)
         {
             float New=(P_totalprice/100)*10;
             float total=P_totalprice-New;
             printf("%f\n",total); 

         }
        if(P_totalprice>=601)
        {
             float New=(P_totalprice/100)*15;
             float total=P_totalprice-New;
             printf("%f\n",total);    
        }  

                break;
            case 'a':
                return 1;
            default:
                ;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void chech_out (struct Product *product)
    {
        printf("%2.f",product->potatoes);
    }
```

I get the error message:

```
hj4.c:181:28: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'struct Product'
hj4.c:181:28: runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'float'
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==1476==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x000000422814 bp 0x7ffd19c2f280 sp 0x7ffd19c2f260 T1476)
==1476==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1476==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x422813  (/root/sandbox/hj4+0x422813)
    #1 0x42246e  (/root/sandbox/hj4+0x42246e)
    #2 0x42232a  (/root/sandbox/hj4+0x42232a)
    #3 0x7f11cd86fb96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #4 0x402ae9  (/root/sandbox/hj4+0x402ae9)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==1476==ABORTING
```

I guess I just need some pointers to solve this problem;)

Comment: Using inexact datatypes like `float` and `double` are not suitable for holding monetary values, they may give you "weird" results when doing calculations. And using global variables for passing function parameters  or return values is typically not recommended either. It makes the functions non threadsafe, non reentrant, wastes memory, and most important, hard to read, especially when you use non-descriptive names like `number`.

Comment: Did you get any compile-warnings when compiling your program? If not, turn on warnings with `-Wall`. Then try to understand and fix the warnings. If you have any problems with that, I recommend to post a new question where you include the warning messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why your compiler is not warning about this, but your `chech_out` function is declared up top as `chech_out()` - with no parameters - but the *definition* includes one: `chech_out(struct Product *product)`.  When the function is called, it's treating garbage on the stack as a pointer to a product, and failing.

Edit: the reason the compiler is not warning is because declaring functions up top with just open+close parentheses means the parameter list is undefined (to be compatible with older versions of C): if a function truly takes no parameters, defined them as `int myfunction(void)` where the `void` says "I take no parameters"

To fix this

```
// define struct Product here
void get_number (void);
void show_menu (void);
int get_input (struct Product *);
void chech_out (struct Product *);
```

and now let your compiler tell you what you've missed.